# scipy.interpolate.splrep function is above the data points

Tags: python, scipy, interpolation, spline

I am trying to create a fit for my data so that I can draw random x points from the fit and get the calculate the corresponding y points with scipy.splev

My code is pretty simple.

```
> fit_spline = splrep(x, y, k=1) 
> 
> plt.plot(x,y, '.', 'r')
> 
> plt.plot(fit_spline[0], fit_spline[1]) 
> 
> plt.show()
```

Where x and y are the coordinates of the red points.

I use k=1 because it turned out to fit the points the best. However the spline is consistently shifted up and left of the data the data points and I am not sure how to fix this.

[image: This is another example. The blue line is the interpolation from splrep and the red points are the data points]
[image: The blue line is the interpolation from splrep and the red points are the data points]

Answer (score 0):

Your example code seems to be missing the splev step, as in `splev(x, fit_spline)`